# Laptop sound no longer functioning

Tags: audio

My ASUS ux31 just stopped playing sound. The Device Manager says it's working properly, the drivers are up to date, I've tried disabling and reenabling the sound card drivers, I've tried restarting. This is a problem with and without headphones. Laptop runs windows 7. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Check your volume control. You may have muted everything.

Comment: He says he tried his 'phones.

Comment: I assure you, I have thought to quadruple check the actual volume setting.

Comment: I'd try booting from a linux live usb to see if it is a broken soundcard or a Windows issue

Answer (score 0):

Look at your playback devices. It might be that you have set an HDMI or USB device as your default playback device. In that situation, you will never hear anything!

Comment: It says my playback device is my speakers. As for a linux usb, idk where to find one.

Comment: Do you see the VU meters on the right of your playback device light up with green bars when you play music? If not then there is something muted before (check the audio mixer, by selecting recording devices, right click under the last device and enable the mixer. Then check the properties of the mixer [Tab2]), otherwise it might be that you have a loose cable.

Comment: I can see the green bars when I attempt to change the volume (using the ping noise as my sound test).

Comment: The laptop's less than a year old, so I doubt the sound card suddenly quit on me.

Comment: One question. Some laptops have an old fashion "knob" on the side or front to turn the volume up/down. Any chance your laptop has one? Also have you checked if you have accidentally changed any audio setting with the Fn function keys?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Linux LiveCD.
If you boot with such a CD, it will run Linux from the CD. Nothing get's installed. As soon as you remove the CD, your PC will run as before.

Make sure that the boot sequence (in your BIOS) is set to use CD before the hard disk.
**Do NOT install Linux, only select the LiveCD option.**

Most downloads will use an ISO format. You can create a bootable CD from such an ISO image with a program called ImgBurn.

Burning:
http://www.imgburn.com/

LiveCD Options:
http://www.knopper.net/knoppix/index-en.html

http://livecdlist.com/operating-system/linux

Answer (score 0):

Well, it may be a hardware issue after all. My gf apparently spilled water on the table my laptop was on yesterday and ma not have saved it in time. Also, my mic's not functioning either. Please tell me there's a solution besides replacement.